# Error while Inserting Data through Thunderclient into MONGODB

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mern

I'm new in using MERN Stack & I'm trying to connect Mongo and Node but facing this issue while inserting Data into Database, using MongoDb Compass

Index.js

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express')
connectToMongo();

const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.json())

//Available Routes
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/notes'))

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
        name:{
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        email:{
            type:String,
            require:true,
            unique: true
        },
        password:{
            type:String,
            require:true
        },
        timestamp:{
            type:Date,
            default:Date.now
        }
  });

  module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema)
```

auth.js

```
const express=require('express');
const User = require('../models/User');
const router=express.Router()


router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        const user = User(req.body)
        user.save()
        res.send(req.body)
})


module.exports = router
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"

const connectToMongo=()=>{
    mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI,()=>{
        console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully")
    })
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

ThunderClient Request:

```
{
  "name":"pratik",
  "email":"pratik@mail.com",
  "password":"6626"
}
```

Error:
const err = new MongooseError(message);
^

MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (D:\Study\React\MERN\inotebook\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:175:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

I guess the problem is because of the newer version, I'm trying to read the Docs and StackOverFlow but unable to Solve this Error what should I Do

Comment: The problem here is, it is not connecting to MongoDB. It may be due to not listing IP address or DNS error  or connection error. First try using async and await. If not solved follow this thread https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseerror-operation-users-insertone-buffering-timed-out-after-10000ms/143993

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are not connected to mongo actually.
You miss async/await in db.js

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
await mongoose.connect(mongoURI,
// you can add this opts
      { keepAlive: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })

console.log("Connected to Mongo Successfully")
```

}

And also later when you are calling user.save() it also should be async:

```
async (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = User(req.body)
    await user.save()
    res.send(req.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone
the Solution was quite simple,
Just Change your localhost to 127.0.0.1:270